# How to load XML object into Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, datatable

I am a completely newbie to jQuery,AJAX and Datatables and in programming in general. What I am trying to achieve is to display multiple news feeds into a datatable. So I created an array including the feeds I need to get information from and my question is how can I convert the xml object into an acceptable type(JSON?)in order for the table to be able to receive the information.
What I have tried so far:

```
$.ajax(feed[i], {
  accepts: {
    xml: "application/rss+xml"
  },
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(data) {
$(document).ready(function() {


      $('#example').DataTable({
         "ajax": {
           "dataType": "xml",
           "url": feed[i],
            "dataSrc":  function() {

          }
},
        retrieve: true,
        columns: [{
          data: "some_info"
        }, {
          data: "some_info"
        }, {
          data: "some_info"
        }, {
          data: "some_info"
        }]
      });
    });
  }
});
}
});
```

Where "feed" is the array with the links from the news feeds, "data" is the XML object which I believe should be converted inside Ajax request at "dataSrc": function(){}.
 Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You will need to learn how to map the xml to javascript array first...then pass new data array to plugin and initialize. Or perhaps use a service to do the transformation for you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean something like jQuery.parseXML()? Can you be more detailed please?

Comment: that would be used to work with the xml...it then needs to be parsed into javascript array of data from that parsed xml